# Ссылка на вектор теряется по пути

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

У меня есть .h файл в котором описан всего один класс Worker:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    class Worker {
    private:
        std::vector<int> num_mas;
    public:
        void pushElem(int n) {
            num_mas.push_back(n);
        }

        void printElem() {
            for (int i = 0; i < num_mas.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << num_mas[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        std::vector<int> getMas() {
            return num_mas;
        }

Worker() {
    num_mas.reserve(5);
    std::cout << "Конструктор по умолчанию";
}
};
```

И две формы MyForm и DataForm. Чтобы не засорять сообщение скину только участки кода по которым есть вопросы.

Изначально в функции main запускается форма MyForm. В .h файле формы описана переменная типа Worker

```
Worker w1;
```

В конструкторе MyForm я заношу в поле num_mas несколько элементов:

```
w1.pushElem(10);
w1.pushElem(15);
w1.pushElem(5);
```

Дальше при нажатии кнопки выполняется следующий код:

```
private: System::Void Button13_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    FormData^ f = gcnew FormData(w1.getMas());
    f->Show();
}
```

То есть я хочу передать копию вектора из этого объекта, чтобы конструктор формы FormData ее обработал ну и сделал с ней свои дела

Код я там почти не трогал, только добавил текстовое поле. В классе формы находится два конструктора:

```
 FormData(std::vector<int> numbers) {
    richTextBox1->AppendText("Hello");
 }

 FormData(void)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    richTextBox1->AppendText("Hello");
 }
```

Программа нормально компилируется, но когда нажимаю кнопку вылетает ошибка:

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
```

Если вызывать обычный конструктор то программа работает нормально

Еще хочу добавить, что объект я создал правильно. (То есть вряд ли дело в этом). На месте вызова конструктора, был код который печатал содержимое поля num_mas:

w1.printElem();

Comment: Еще замечу, что в приведенном коде нет ни одной ссылки на вектор, сообщение об ошибке не имеет никакого отношения к ссылкам на вектор, а отличие в конструкторах очевидно.

Comment: Извините я только учусь программировать. Я согласен, что ссылки на вектор тут нет, а название такое выбрано из-за текста ошибки: "ссылка на экземпляр объекта", в которой как мне кажется под объектом понимается вектор. Можете тогда объяснить тогда в чем конкретно произошла ошибка?

Comment: Посмотрите, для чего в конструкторе нужен вызов `InitializeComponent();` и чем грозит его отсутствие.

Comment: Спасибо, вот в чем была ошибка) Можете добавить ответ, чтобы я его отметил как полезный. Я впервые вот работаю с windows forms поэтому на эту вещь как-то и не обратил внимания

Answer (score 0):

В перегруженном конструкторе надо было добавить

```
InitializeComponent();
```